Best way to add custom attributes to python logger ( Filters vs SetLogRecordFactory)
My usecase is, I would like to add some global parameters to each log, which should get added itself when logs get emitted, that means defined as a property of logger instance that is used across the application without having to explicitly add with each logline.
Further I would like to access it when defining format of log in the way
format='%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s user_id %(customattr)-15s: %(message)s'
So far I have come across two ways to add custom attributes to the logs via

SetLogRecordFactory


`_former_log_record_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def _log_record_uuid_injector(*args, **kwargs):
    record = _former_log_record_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.uuid = uuid.uuid4()  # or another implementation of uuid
    return record

# set the new factory
logging.setLogRecordFactory(_log_record_uuid_injector)


Filters - suggested here
Python Logging : how to add a custom field to LogRecord, and register a global callback to sets it's value

I would like to know the difference in both the approaches, their pros & cons, and which is more suitable option in terms of performance and robustness.
